# CopyToLocal Attribute for dll property not showing

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005

I have copied source code from development server to my local machine. But I am getting dll errors(Ajaxcontroltoolkit dll). So when I try to make the CopyToLocal property to True, I cannot see a property named COpyToLocal for the dll. So how to fix it.
Screenshot is given below.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wGya.png
```

Comment: Look at the properties of that file with Windows Explorer.  If you see the "Unblock" button then click that button.  After checking that you got the file from a reputable source.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the dll issue by giving full permission to temp asp.net folder in C drive. Hope it may help someone.